# Returning malloced pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* getStr(int length) {
    char* chars = malloc(length + 1);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
        chars[i] = 'X';
    chars[i] = '\0';
    // no call to free()
    return chars;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char* str;
    str = getStr(10);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It prints 10 `X`'s, as I expected.
Would it behave like this on any platform with any compiler?
Is the memory still malloced after `getStr()` returns?

(I don't want to pass the pointer as argument :D)

Comment: Yes the memory is still allocated after the function returns.

Comment: It's well defined on all platforms and systems. If you allocate memory using `malloc` it stays allocated until you explicitly call `free`. (Most major operating systems also free allocated memory when the process exits.)

Comment: Please do not forget to check the pointer for `NULL` before dereferencing the pointer, it might just be a simple example, but please do not forget it, you will not regret it.

Comment: `// no call to free()`  - means the memory is still allocated. The address is viable for the given allocation length so long as (a) `malloc` succeeded, and (b) the address has not been sent to `free()` or `realloc()`. Thus the importance you retain the address, as losing it instigates a *memory leak*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the code looks valid and the behavior should be reliable with any C compiler.

And, yes, the memory is still allocated after `getStr()` returns. So the call to `free()` is also correct.

Don't forget to check if `malloc()` returns `NULL`, in the event there is insufficient memory.

Comment: I'm calling `free()` in `main()` - third line from bottom - is it ok?

Answer (score 3):

If you use `malloc` to allocate memory, it will remain allocated until you explicitly call `free` on it, regardless of how it's passed around between functions, returned, etc.